# Laravel need to get data only from second table linked in first table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have news table, it's about 5000 rows, and each row has building id:

```
public function building()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Building::class);
}
```

so, Building has status name.
I need to select all statuses, but show only if any article has it. I tried:

```
$news->pluck('building.status')->unique()->filter()->toArray();
```

It works fine, but took about 70mb of memory. So, it's not ok for my case. I found one solution, seems like it took just 3mb

```
News::with(['building' => function($query){ $query->groupBy('status'); }])->get();
```

But I need to get only statuses without any different info to prevent filter on PHP side.
How I can get it? Maybe different ways? Thanks!

Comment: This obviously should be solved with SQL, not with a `Collection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
News::with('building')->get()->pluck('building.status')->unique()->values();
```

This is called Eager Loading as we have to specify related relationship to optimize sql queries. Read about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: it works and took just 1mb of memory, very thanks!!!